# How to write this code with bind & fmap?

Tags: haskell

How can you write the function transaction without do-notation, using bind & fmap?

```
    transaction :: UTCTime -> EncUser -> STM (Either Text ())
    transaction now user = do
      dbData <- readTVar db
      case isValidRequest dbData of
        Right _ -> do confirmRegistration user
                      return $ Right ()
        Left err -> return $ Left err
      where isValidRequest = registrationExists >=> isConfirmationValid now

    confirmRegistration :: EncUser -> STM () 
    registrationExists :: DbData -> Either Text Registration
    isConfirmationValid :: UTCTime -> Registration -> Either Text Registration
```

My attempt is along these lines:

```
    transaction :: UTCTime -> EncUser -> STM (Either Text ())
    transaction now user = do
      readTVar db
      >>= return . isValidRequest
      >>= fmap (confirmRegistration user)
      where isValidRequest = registrationExists >=> isConfirmationValid now
```

...but the compilation fails with the error bellow and I can't seem to understand how to fmap confirmRegistration on top of the Either result produced by isValidRequest

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘Either Text’ with ‘STM’
>   Expected type: Either Text Registration -> STM (Either Text ())
>     Actual type: STM Registration -> STM (Either Text ())
> • In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely
>     ‘fmap (confirmRegistration user)’
>   In the expression:
>     do { readTVar db } >>= return . isValidRequest
>     >>= fmap (confirmRegistration user)
>   In an equation for ‘transaction’:
>       transaction now user
>         = do { readTVar db } >>= return . isValidRequest
>           >>= fmap (confirmRegistration user)
>         where
>             isValidRequest = registrationExists >=> isConfirmationValid now
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do` notation is fairly mechanical:

```
transaction now user =
  readTVar db >>= \dbData ->
  case isValidRequest dbData of
    Right _ -> confirmRegistration user >>
               return (Right ())
    Left err -> return $ Left err
  where isValidRequest = registrationExists >=> isConfirmationValid now
```

Comment: the above case-of expression is very similar to Either's fmap implementation so this is why I would like to use a fmap instead case-of

Comment: @vidi You can't, because you have `confirmRegistration user >>` in there. Without it you could extract `return` like this: `return (case isValidRequest dbData of Right _ -> Right (); Left err -> Left err)`, which is `return (fmap (const ()) (isValidRequest dbData))`. But that's not what you have.

Comment: Now I realized that the type of confirmRegistration is wrong here. I'll fix the types and be back. Thanks. In the meanwhile you are right, given the types in the original question

Answer (score 0):

This is final code after I fixed the type for confirmRegistration, after the comments from melpomene. I'm posting this as a reference because it looks very close to what I wanted in the first place.

```
transaction :: UTCTime -> Text -> EncUser -> STM (Either Text ())
transaction now rid user = do
  readTVar db
  >>= sequence . confirmRegistration user <.> isValidRequest
  where isValidRequest = findRegistration rid >=> isConfirmationValid now

confirmRegistration :: EncUser -> Registration -> STM ()
findRegistration :: Text -> DbData -> Either Text Registration
isConfirmationValid :: UTCTime -> Registration -> Either Text Registration
```

Note: The operator <.> is "functor composition" found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yjtools-0.9.18/docs/Control-Applicative-Tools.html#v:-60-.-62-)

Still I'm missing the intuition why is **sequence** needed there but I should probably post that as a different question.